# undocumented gitweb output: trailing m in tree listing

Tags: git

I have a git repository where apparently everything is well (I don't matter piwik listed files):

```
# git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   piwik/tmp/cache/tracker/piwikcache_1.php
        modified:   piwik/tmp/cache/tracker/piwikcache_general.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

However, there is a subdirectory which isn't tracked by git, it hasn't any .gitignore file in it, nor have I any global ignore rule.

In gitweb every other directory is listed this way:

```
drwxr-xr-x  -   gooddir tree | history
```

while the untracked one is listed this way:

```
m---------  -   failingdir  history
```

It hasn't a link in it like the other directories, and clicking on history I get:

```
500 - Unknown type of object
```

What does the trailing m mean? I couldn't find it in the docs

Why isn't the directory tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory shown as `m---------` in gitweb is actually [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).